# событие onchange срабатывает при сворачивании окна браузера

Tags: javascript, onchange

Подскажите, есть `input`. Нужно отловить событие, когда ввод данных в поле будет завершен. По этому событию будет обновляться запись в БД и сниматься блокировка. Ввод считается завершенным, пользователь щелкнул вне поля на этой странице, ну или нажал `tab`. В общем, сошел с записи. Кнопку делать не могу, нужно именно поле обрабатывать.

Проблема в том, что `onchange`, как и `focusout`, срабатывает, если уйти с вкладки или свернуть браузер. Я понимаю, при этих действиях, наверное, теряется фокус поля и запускается `onchange`. Но если окно открыть обратно страницу с полем, фокус у поля есть и каретка в том месте, где была при сворачивании и это дает надежду, что можно что-то сделать.

Как можно выйти из ситуации, есть ли какой-то способ не запускать событие при сворачивании браузера?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось только задержать обработку event примерно следующим образом:

```js
// Можем ли мы производить действие (да или нет)
var canTakeAction = true;

// Обработчик события, вызываемый через малое время
function takeAction() {
  if (canTakeAction) {
    console.log("We take action")
  }
}

// Общая функция для изменения видимости
function handleVisibilityChange(newValue) {
    canTakeAction = newValue;
}

// Если у нас вкладка поменялась
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {

    if (document.hidden) {
        handleVisibilityChange(false);
    } else {
        handleVisibilityChange(true);
    }
});

// документ доступен
document.addEventListener('focus', function (evt) {
    handleVisibilityChange(true);
}, false);
// документ теряет фокус
document.addEventListener('blur', function (evt) {
    handleVisibilityChange(false);
}, false);
//окно доступно
window.addEventListener('focus', function () {
    handleVisibilityChange(true);
}, false);
// окно теряет фокус
window.addEventListener('blur', function () {
    handleVisibilityChange(false);
}, false);
```

```html
<!-- Вызываем обработчик события через малое время, чтобы глобальные события уже отработали -->
<input onblur="setTimeout(takeAction,100)">
 <!-- -->
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, интересно получилось. Я сейчас пробую пойти другим путем: просто обрабатывать клик вне поля и нажатие tab. Завтра опишу тоже в виде ответа. Потом попробую Ваш способ. Задержка хоть и небольшая, но все-таки не хотелось бы.